# What's the difference between the [blog] and [blog-overflow] tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, meta

I noticed there's a [blog](/questions/tagged/blog) tag and a [blog-overflow](/questions/tagged/blog-overflow) tag. What's the difference between these two tags, if any?

The tag wiki excerpt for [blog](/questions/tagged/blog) states:

> This tag signifies that the question somehow relates to one of the SE community blogs.

The Blog Overflow site hosts the SE community blogs, which makes me think these two tags are synonyms of one another.

I suggest merging [blog-overflow](/questions/tagged/blog-overflow) into [blog](/questions/tagged/blog) unless there is a significant difference between the two tags that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like that excerpt for blogs is wrong.

On [blog](/questions/tagged/blog), you'd hear the gnashing that is brought on by the mouthpiece written by the employees of Stack Exchange.

Which would then leave you with the clawing (no, not cloying) of the [blog-overflow](/questions/tagged/blog-overflow), which rounds up the community driven blogs that are spear-headed by the various Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Story time! Story time!